# Фильтрация нелицензионного контента возможна?

Tags: безопасность, фильтрация

Попалась информация, что [Starlink уведомляет пользователей о скачивании нелицензионного контента и угрожает разорвать с ними договор если это будет продолжаться](https://www.yaplakal.com/forum1/topic2264886.html). Как технически может быть организована подобная проверка? По миом представлениям во-первых, от анализа трафика должен защищать https, а во-вторых, даже если нечто скачивается в открытом виде, то непонятно, как можно отличить пиратский контент от законно купленного. Ну и вряд ли это чёрные списки сайтов, поскольку в таком случае гораздо логичнее на них просто не пускать, чем сначала пускать, а потом лишать пользователя интернета.

Comment: Нам это (Starlink) в обозримом будущем не грозит. Нам нашего РКН достаточно. Вот о чем думать надо...

Comment: @avp, но Starlink - это всего лишь провайдер. Если такое могут сделать они, то и любой другой провайдер сможет. И оборудование того же РКН сможет. Но я не понимаю, как это возможно...

Comment: Может, на самом деле ничего особенного и просто банально торренты анализируют?

Comment: анализ dns запросов никто не отменял. Во вторых, торрент активность можно достаточно легко отличить от обычной, многие торренты просто кричат в сеть "я тут, у меня есть что скачать" - провайдер без проблем такое может проанализировать. В третьих, всегда есть "правообладатели" и те, кто себя такими считает - они тоже хорошо все ищут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Письма о нелицензионном контенте идут уже давно. Обычные российские сейчас провайдеры просто игнорируют их.

*Минимум с 2009 идут такие письма - тогда долго думали, что с этими письмами делать. И первые несколько переправили абоненту с похожими словами. Потом подумали, что представитель правообладателя в другом правовом поле и нет подходящего закона в России. Отправили письма в спам.*

Одна из технологий обнаружения для торента очень проста. Антипираты находят популярные пиратские раздачи и встают специально модифицированным клиентом на раздачу. При обмене пирами передается список блоков и ip адреса других участников. Хоть эти данные и зашифрованы для провайдера - они открыты для торент клиентов.

Старлинк угрозы правообладателей с ловушкой переложил на клиента.

В письме провайдеру указан IP и имя скачанного файла.

Для онлайн просмотра блокировка сайтов возможна, но затратна и не решает проблемы. Вспомните реестр РКН и ковровые блокировки Телеграмма - в другой стране можно получить иски на ущерб.

Comment: Получается, правообладатель отследил торрент, а провайдер просто переслал письмо, добавив немного от себя? Хотя в скриншоте письма по ссылке я ни ip, ни имени файла не увидел. И угроза оставить без интернета смотрится странно - ну пусть между собой разбираются, а посреднику-то зачем лезть?

Comment: @Qwertiy провайдеру проще  отказаться от клиента чем разбираться или он заключил соглашение с правообладателями напряму - это объясняет отсебятину. В письмах 2009ого года было имя файла и время загрузки, контакты ловца и правообладателя. Письмо пришло на почту указаннаю как абуз в райпе на диапазон адресов нашего маленького провайдера. Врятли найду письмо чтоб показать наглядно - не работаю в провайдере сейчас

Comment: https://github.com/sunsmoke/bithammer вот например софтинка для поиска качальщиков в локальной сети